# How to display GPX file in CesiumJS

Tags: javascript, gps, cesiumjs, gpx

I would like to display a gpx file into my cesium viewer on a HTML page but I don't manage to find how.
I have the example from the official tutorial of Cesium but the data used there is like :

```
const dataPoint = { longitude: -122.38985, latitude: 37.61864, height: -27.32 };
```

How can I translate my gpx file so that the program could read it ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: try to convert your GPX to KML and load.

Answer (score 1):

There exists support for gpx file in Cesium now. You can load your gpx file in the viewer using the following feature:

```
viewer.dataSources.add(Cesium.GpxDataSource.load(
  "../../xyz.gpx",
  {
    clampToGround: true,
  }
);
```